# Flatten list and push list key to vector on second level

Tags: r, list, transpose

I suppose this is simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out. 
I need to flatten the second level structure and push the list name/key to a vector on the same level as the other vectors. The current structure of `myList` is

```
$ 13454:List of 30
  ..$ subjectId        : num 187
  ..$ procedureId      : num 3
  ..$ procedureSampleId: num 3
  ..$ timestamp        : chr "2017-04-21T17:15:10.911Z"
  ..$ n001             : num -999
  ..$ n002             : num -999
  ..$ gender           : num 1
  ..$ age              : num 18

 $ 13455:List of 30
  ..$ subjectId        : num 188
  ..$ procedureId      : num 3
  ..$ procedureSampleId: num 3
  ..$ timestamp        : chr "2017-04-21T17:15:10.913Z"
  ..$ n001             : num -999
  ..$ n002             : num -999      
  ..$ gender           : num -999
  ..$ age              : num 28
```

whereas this is the structure I'm looking for

```
 $ ID               : chr  '13455' '13455'
 $ subjectId        : num 187 188
 $ procedureId:     : num  3 3
```

and so on

I've tried to achieve this by:

```
  myList2 <- sapply(names(myList), function(y){
    y <- unlist(c('ID' = y, myList[[y]]), use.names = TRUE)
  })
```

But I end up with the full transposed result of what I need. I could go `t(myList2)` but I want to understand how to do this correctly. Thank you!

EDIT: Reproducible data:

```
myList <- list('13454' = list('subjectId' = 187, 'procedureId' = 3, 'procedureSampleId' = 3, 'timestamp' = "2017-04-21T17:15:10.911Z", 'n001' = -999, 'n002' = -999, 'gender' = 1, 'age' = 18), '13455' = list('subjectId' = 188, 'procedureId' = 3, 'procedureSampleId' = 3, 'timestamp' = "2017-04-21T17:15:10.913Z", 'n001' = -999, 'n002' = -999, 'gender' = -999, 'age' = 28))
```

Comment: What you say you want and what you show you want are not the same thing. If you want a data.frame, `rbind` it all together, e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows(myList, .id = 'ID')`. Either way, you need [to make your example reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) by adding sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myList` can be turned into a data.frame using `lapply()` and `rbindlist()` from the `data.table` package:

```
result <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(myList, as.data.frame), idcol = "ID")
result[["ID"]] <- names(myList)
result
#      ID subjectId procedureId procedureSampleId                timestamp n001 n002 gender age
#1: 13454       187           3                 3 2017-04-21T17:15:10.911Z -999 -999      1  18
#2: 13455       188           3                 3 2017-04-21T17:15:10.913Z -999 -999   -999  28
```

**Edit**: This can be even more streamlined:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(myList, idcol = "ID")[, ID := names(myList)][]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** To get to the list format you indicate above in base R, use `rbind` to build the data frame, then unlist the necessary elements with `lapply`.

With your list above, you can use `do.call` to call `rbind` in base R:

```
example<-data.frame(ID = as.character(names(myList)), do.call("rbind", myList), row.names = NULL)
exAsList <-lapply(example, function(x) x <- unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))
exAsList
```